# Automatically make a cells value '£20.00' if they enter a value above '£20.00'?

Tags: microsoft-excel

is it possible to automatically make a cells value '£20.00' if the user enters a value above '£20.00' & if the value entered is less than '£20.00' it would display the actual entered value.

**For example:**

In cell A1 the user enters £12.50 and the cell displays £12.50.

In cell A2 the user enters £21.50 but the cell only displays £20.00.

Essentially adding a hard limit on the value that can be entered. I know you can use data validation to add a limit, but it doesn't fill in the cell with the max allowed value if the user enters something above it, it just pops up a warning.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a bodge, but if you don't want to use macros to change the actual value, you could use a custom format to stop the data entry cell displaying values above £20 (as in @PeterH's answer), but use a hidden cell to calculate the value you want to use, e.g.

```
=MIN(A2, 20)
```

Alternatively, if you only need to use the capped value in a couple of places, you could incorporate a similar formula in the place where you use the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom number format for this.

```
[<20]£00.00;[>=20]"£20.00"
```

Select the cells this should apply to, and right click, format cells.

Under the number tab, select Custom, and use the format above.

Comment: Will it affect the cell *value* used in further calculations? or just the display?

Comment: While this works in showing anything above £20.00 as £20.00. It doesn't get calculated as such. Is there any way around this?

Comment: In Excel, using the conditional format does not affect the cell's actual value. However, if you copy-n-paste the cell to a different app (e.g. Notepad), the displayed value will be pasted, rather than the calculated one.

Answer (score 2):

Place the following worksheet event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim CheckCells As Range, r As Range, rINT As Range
    Set CheckCells = Range("A2")
    Set rINT = Intersect(CheckCells, Target)

    If rINT Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In rINT
            If r.Value > 20 Then r.Value = 20
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = False
End Sub
```

It will monitor inputs to cell **A2** and limit them to 20.  If you want to place the same restrictions on other cells, you can do it by changing a single line of code.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I've read that macros do no work in the online version of excel. While I use the desktop version, so of the people that will use this worksheet are only in the online version, will this still display correctly online?

Comment: @SaxonRix  **will not work online** ............suggest you use JRI's approach.